# couchdb error while accessing a view "file corruption"?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have a couchdb installation which generally opens fine at futon, in "All documents" view i can see all the objects; however when i try accessing one of my views, i get this error after a couple of seconds "Error: file_corruption file corruption" in an alert dialog box.
The db has been moved between discs in past, as we changed the disks to make sure that we have enough space.
if the file is corrupt, it shouldn't work at all, is there any way i could repair the same.
The db is quite big already more than 150 GB; I even tried making the same view with diff name but the error persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that moving files is a bad idea. You should better [replicate](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication) your DB from old server to the new one.

```
$ curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://newserver:5984/_replicate -d ' {"source": "http://oldserver:5984/foo", "target": "bar", "create_target": true} '
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the couchdb index files and try again
they are located at either

```
/var/lib/couchdb/.{dbname}_design/
/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb/.{dbname}_design/
```